# 'init(nilLiteral:)' is deprecated: use JSON.null instead. Will be removed in future versions

Tags: json, swift, swift4, swifty-json

When I use myProject to `Swift4` and `Xcode9` gives me working code;

```
if (json["Records"] != nil) {
```

gives ;

> 'init(nilLiteral:)' is deprecated: use JSON.null instead. Will be removed in future versions

warning underline nil. Also Im using `SwiftyJSON`
Which way best for fixing it ?

Comment: Eh? `use JSON.null instead` — that's what you should do.

Comment: @user28434 result != JSON.null right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to do, so 'if json["Records"] != JSON.null {'

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper, Yep. And I guess you can omit `JSON` part here and just use `.null`, like with any other `enum` case.

Comment: @user28434 can you answer it I will approve firstly u fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like creators of your `JSON` parsing library dropped support of [ExpressibleByNilLiteral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebynilliteral), that allowed implicit conversion between `nil` and `JSON.null`.

So now you have to explicitly state `JSON.null`(or `.null` if type is inferable) instead. Meaning you need to do :

```
if (json["Records"] != JSON.null) {
   // code
}
```